# How might I find a render array of a parent OG group?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

If given the node id, how may I get that node's menu's render array?

I'm almost looking for an API function such as

```
function get_menu_for_node($nid) {}
```

Where this would return the render array to which node/$nid belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to achieve this. I'm still not happy with the results but given time pressures, it'll have to do. I'm posting to see if anyone can suggests a better alternative.

I grab the nid of the parent group first and use it to do a query against `menu_links`. Once I have a result of a menu_id(s), we loop through, get the links, use `theme()`, and then `drupal_add_region_content()`.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 *
 * This module creates a block that looks for any parent OG group and displays the menu of that
 * group. 
 */

define('_OGPN_NODETYPE', 'user_posted_content');
define('_OGPARENTNAME_TITLE', 'OG Parent Menu');


/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function ogparentmenu_block_info() {
    // This example comes from node.module.
    $blocks['_ogparentmenu'] = array(
        'info' => t(_OGPARENTNAME_TITLE),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );


    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function ogparentmenu_block_view($delta = '') {
        return [
            'subject' => t(_OGPARENTNAME_TITLE),
            'content' => __ogparentmenu(),
        ] ;
}


/**
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
function __ogparentmenu() {

    $node = menu_get_object();

    /* Set up menu on UserPosts  */
    if ($node->type == _OGPN_NODETYPE) {

        // get parent link of og
        $parent_og = filter_var($node->og_group_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        // Query menu_links based on node/$nid path
        $menu_query = db_select('menu_links', 'ml')
            ->fields('ml', ['menu_name', 'mlid'])
            ->condition('link_path', "node/$parent_og", '=')
            ->execute();

        // if single
        if ($menu_query->rowCount() == 1) {
            $menu_id = check_plain($menu_query->fetchAs()['menu_name']);
            $links = menu_navigation_links($menu_id);

            $themed_menu = theme('links__system_main_menu', [
                '#title' => t('title'),
                'links' => $links,
                'attributes' => [
                    'class' => ['user_post_menu_injected', 'section']
                ],

            ]);

            return $themed_menu;





        }
        // TO DO : handle multiple
        elseif ($menu_query->rowCount() > 1) {

            return 'null';
        }



    }
}
```